# Amplitude Modulation

Tags: transistors, amplitude-modulation

[image]

Hello, I'm new to this topic as it is my school works, I try to simulate the diagram below by using Proteus which I follow accordingly with the labsheet given from my school.

The problem is the parameters for the Carrier Wave & Audio Signal is unknown while VCC=15V. There's no output when I run the simulation. Can someone suggest me to solve this problem?

The parameters for R & C were already given in the labsheet which I just follow it and should not be changed.

Updates : I try to run the same circuit by using Multisim and it does generates waveform. But now the question is, what parameters should I change to get the best AM modulation ?

[image]

Comment: All the inputs to the 'scope are connected to Ground - is that what you want?

Comment: Your "scope" is not measuring the output.

Comment: I've change the ground and it solved the problem ! But how to find the best parameters for this AM output waveform ?

Comment: If you've changed the wiring, please post a revised schematic so we know how your actualcircuit is connected.

Comment: https://imgur.com/3Cu0KOy

Comment: The base of the transistor is biased to 5V so the peak carrier voltage should be somewhat less than that to avoid going negative and clipping the signal.  We don’t know the Hfe of the transistor and so it’s hard to predict the voltage gain, so the carrier voltage might need to be smaller again.  The audio signal needs to be smaller in amplitude than the carrier that emerges from the collector of the transistor.  If you have to guess, start with 100mVrms for the carrier and adjust that until you’re getting a reasonable output, maybe 5V peak-to-peak, and then mix in maybe 2V peak-to-peak audio.

Comment: It seems different with the AM waveform I've seen in the youtube. Am I doing it right ?

Comment: Oh and if you don’t have anything else to go on, use 1MHz carrier and 1kHz audio.

Comment: @Azim you don’t appear to have a ground connection in that image

Comment: @Frog Im a bit confused, which nodes should I put a ground connection ?

Comment: Where you had ground in the original question

Comment: https://imgur.com/Ux8e9jo

Comment: Yes just there :-)

Comment: Once i put the ground there, every waveform dissapeared. Thats why I deleted it.

Comment: I don’t know why that would happen :-(

Comment: @Azim Please edit the question with the new image (you may want to crop it) Please also ask a specific question

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and didnt know that I can update the question. Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of schematic glitches:

1. Scope signals (obvious)
2. The load R must be >= Rc in for large swing to not starve the collector signal of current when AC coupled.